# Select desired target .NET version in .NET Upgrade Assistant

Tags: .net, visual-studio

My intention is to upgrade my .NET Framework 4.8 projects to .NET 6. Using .NET 6 is important because that is the highest .NET version one of my dependencies supports. I ran the upgrade assistant analyzer on my project and received the following line.

> Recommending Windows TFM **net7.0-windows** because the project either has Windows-specific dependencies or builds to a WinExe

Is there any way to set the target version to .NET 6 in the .NET Upgrade Assistant?

Comment: That's a recommendation. Is there no other option? Eg `net6.0-windows` ?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it looks as if the [`--target-tfm-support`](https://github.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website#running-the-tool) command line option with the `LTS` value is what you are looking for.
At *this point in time*, .NET 6.0 is the LTS release.

Comment: @Christian.K That was the ticket. Make your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly set the specific version, but you can decide whether to use `LTS` (Long term service release), `Current` (well, the current realease) or `Preview` (the next, upcoming version).

You use the `--target-tfm-support` command line option with either one of these values.

At the time of this writing the situation should be as follows:

- `LTS`: net-6.0
- `Current`: net-7.0
- `Preview`: net-8.0 (or some minor version of net-7.0)

Obviously, this will change over time.

More information and details can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website#running-the-tool).

Answer (score 0):

to migrate to .net6.0 I used below command and it worked successfully :

upgrade-assistant upgrade **-t LTS** project path

For **non-interactive** I used :

upgrade-assistant upgrade **-t LTS**  **--non-interactive**   project path

as of now .net6.0 is LongTermSupport (LTS)